# Installing imagemagick failure

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew

I really suck at computers but need to use them willy-nilly.  Please tell me if I missed vital info, I will try to supply.

My environments:
MacOS 11.1（20C69）
MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
This is an out-of-the-box machine.

What I tried:

- Installed homebrew [using the official terminal command; I don't know what it does but there is now a directory /opt/homebrew/, so it must be the installation location.]
- command line: brew install imagemagick
- command line: brew install ghostscript
- command line: Xcode-select --install [this was suggested in the logs for the first "brew install imagemagick"]
- (, which prompted GUI actions by MacOS)
- Again brewed imagemagick [In case it matters, I was using a temp folder on Desktop as the current directory during the second attempt.]

I think the installation, however, seems unsuccessful:

% `magick convert -version`

zsh: killed     magick convert -version

[Edit: After reading [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/439), I did
`brew reinstall gettext` and
`brew reinstall pcre2`

and the above command is successful finally.  BUT, it fails at:

`convert testimg.jpg testimg.png`

zsh: killed . . .]

**Terminal may kill a process that overburdens the memory, but my test command cannot be burdening!  Please, what is wrong?**

Errors and warnings in the logs for second imagemagick installation:

> Error: Failure while executing; `git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true` was terminated by uncaught signal KILL.

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
> You can try again using `brew postinstall shared-mime-info`

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
> You can try again using `brew postinstall libheif`

> /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 18: 12854 Killed: 9               "$GIT_EXECUTABLE" "$@"
> /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 18: 12855 Killed: 9               "$GIT_EXECUTABLE" "$@"
> /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 18: 12873 Killed: 9               "$GIT_EXECUTABLE" "$@"
> /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh: line 18: 12874 Killed: 9               "$GIT_EXECUTABLE" "$@"

> Error: Failure while executing; `git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true` was terminated by uncaught signal KILL.

Comment: For IM 7 use magick, not convert and not magick convert.  I think you main issue is you use ksh and should be using bash. Sorry, I know little about Homebrew. If you use bash shell, the what do you get from `magick identify -version`. Please show what you get.  If that works, then again in bash shell, try `magick logo: logo.gif` does that work?

Comment: Hi, this is what I got: `% magick identify -version`
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-58 Q16 arm 2021-01-16 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
`% magick logo: logo.gif` Generates a gif file in the curr directory.

Comment: But when I try to convert a jpg to png, this is what I got.  `magick testimg.jpg testimg.png`

-bash: magick: command not found

Comment: and `man` fails for `magick`, `convert`, and `display`.

Comment: Does this work?  `magick logo: logo.jpg`. If that works then try `magick logo.jpg logo.png`

Comment: `magick logo: logo.jpg` fails for bash with "-bash: magick: command not found".  It also fails for zsh.  The error message is different; `zsh: killed     magick logo: logo.jpg`.   Was I supposed to uninstall brew and/or IM that I installed with zsh and reinstall them with bash?

Comment: Something is wrong with your ImageMagick install. It looks like JPG as a delegate is either too old or not properly installed.  So I would remove your install for ZSH and reinstall for BASH.  What is your platform? and what version of ImageMagick were you trying to install.

Comment: My platform is MacOS 11.1 (more details in the OP).  The version I was trying to install is "ImageMagick 7.0.10-58 Q16 arm 2021-01-16", but I really don't care.  I just got it by `brew install imagemagick`.  This, I thought, was the simplest way to get myself IM.  Is it okay to keep homebrew, installed via ZSH?

Comment: I don't know it it was necessary but I uninstalled homebrew from zsh anyway.  Via bash, I installed homebrew and imagemagick.  Then, all the test commands you suggested worked fine.  I also tested them with zsh; worked fine too.  A Big Thank you!